# how to save files on smb shared folder on a python3 script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, smb

I'm working with a Raspberry pi 3 B and a picamera v2. I'm taking pictures with it and I need the pictures to be stored on a shared folder.

The command to save pictures is:

```
picamera.PiCamera().capture('/path/pic.jpg')
```

Thing is this format does not support paths like smb://remote/...
The library pysmb has a SMBHandler module to support smb libraries, but it works with urllib2 which is unsupported on python 3. I couldn't make it work with python 3. Does anyone knows how to work on a smb directory with python 3? Maybe a way to chdir to the remote folder?

Comment: can you navigate to the smb folder in the UI?

Comment: Yes. I can manually copy files to the folder from the raspberry, but I want to do it from the script.

Comment: you should be able to navigate to that folder, and "open in shell" or whatever the phrase is. That should show you the path you need to use. that should work in python

Comment: Put a line in `/etc/fstab` to mount the Windows directory then it will have a regular, Unix path on your Pi... https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=180133

Answer (score 0):

The path wasn't working as is. My problem was that I was using the SMBHandler and giving that url as an argument to the picamera.capture function. I managed to make it work on python 2 by taking the picture, storing it on the raspberry and then copying the file on the remote folder.

```
director = urllib2.build_opener(SMBHandler)
camara = picamera.PiCamera()
camara.capture('prueba.jpg')
foto = open('prueba.jpg', 'r+')
nombre = 'smb://{}/{}/{}.jpg'.format(ip, carpeta, timestamp)
fh = director.open(nombre, data = foto)
fh.close()
```

I wanted to store the picture directly on the remote folder, but i didn't manage to do it.